# Handling 2 types of users

Tags: c#, xamarin

In my application I have 2 types of users. Basically a seller and a user. Each type will have 3 pages: a profile page (the seller will have a few more attributes like rating, location etc).

My question: is there a way to handle the different types of users in the same view model (profileViewModel). Like in asp .net core there is a function/property that checks what type of model the view received and according to that you can create custom html for your page.

My users also inherit from a IUser where all the common properties are listed and the seller class only adds the ones it has extra.

```
public class Stylist: BaseRecord<Stylist>
{
    public float Rating { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool IsSchedualeVisible { get; set; }
}

public interface IUser
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    int id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Email { get; set; }
    string ProfilePic { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
    string PasswordConfirmation { get; set; }
    string Phone { get; set; }
    bool IsUser { get; set; }
    bool IsEmailVerified { get; set; }
    bool IsPhoneVerified { get; set; }

    object Clone();
}

public abstract class BaseRecord<T> : IUser
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePic { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordConfirmation { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public bool IsUser { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmailVerified { get; set; }
    public bool IsPhoneVerified { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        var newRecord = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        var props = newRecord.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => p.CanRead);
        foreach (var p in props) p.SetValue(newRecord, p.GetValue(this));

        return newRecord;
    }
}

public class User: BaseRecord<User>
{
}
```

Right now I'm saving in App.cs a IUser object, after logging, and I use it in ProfileViewModel but I still have extra properties for Stylist that I guess I would have to make a type check in both view model and view but that doesn't seem very right

Comment: Just add 3 extra stylist properties to User to merge. If you have 2 different classes, in some cases you can need extra hundreds lines of code. And what do you need  object Clone() for? reflections take 1000 times longer to create object then using new.

Comment: Yes you would make a type check like (user is Type) and then cast it as the required type to get properties of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to handle the different types of users in the same view model (profileViewModel). Like in asp .net core there is a function/property that checks what type of model the view received and according to that you can create custom html for your page.

you can create a Xamarin.Forms DataTemplateSelector to choose a DataTemplate at runtime based on the value of a data-bound property. I do one sample about choose one item from ListView, then choose DataTemplate to display selecteditem.

Model class, using type property to  distinguish User and Seller.

```
public enum ptype
{
    User,
    Seller
}
public class person
{
    public ptype type { get; set; }
    public string name{ get;set;}
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string selleraddress { get; set; }
}

  <ListView ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding persons}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

 public partial class Page4 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<person> persons { get; set; }
    public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        persons = new ObservableCollection<person>()
        {
            new person(){type=ptype.User, name="user",age=18},
            new person(){type=ptype.Seller,name="seller",age=19,selleraddress="this is test"}
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;

    }

    private async void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        person p = (person)e.SelectedItem;
       await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page3(p));
    }
}
```

Then creating DataTemplateSelector

```
public class PersonDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate userTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate sellerTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        return ((person)item).type==ptype.User ? userTemplate : sellerTemplate;
    }
}

<ContentPage
x:Class="FormsSample.datatemplate.Page3"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormsSample.datatemplate">
<ContentPage.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="userTemplate">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding age}" />

        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SellerTemplate">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="DarkBlue">
            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding age}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding selleraddress}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:PersonDataTemplateSelector
        x:Key="personDataTemplateSelector"
        sellerTemplate="{StaticResource SellerTemplate}"
        userTemplate="{StaticResource userTemplate}" />

</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout
        Margin="10"
        BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource personDataTemplateSelector}"
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding persons}" />
   
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
 public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<person> persons { get; set; }
    //private person _user;
    //public person user
    //{
    //    get { return _user; }
    //    set
    //    {
    //        _user = value;
    //        RaisePropertyChanged("user");
    //    }
    //}
    public Page3(person p)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        persons = new ObservableCollection<person>();
        persons.Add(p);
        //user = p;
      
        this.BindingContext = this;           
    }    
}
```

Now I can choose different DataTemplate according to person type. You can modify my code according to your requirement.

**Update:**

Yes, you can create one User class and Seller class, Seller class inherit User class.

```
 public class user
{
    public ptype type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Seller:user
{
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string products_to_sell { get; set; }
}
```

Then changing Corresponding person class to User class.

```
 public partial class Page4 : ContentPage
{
  
    public ObservableCollection<user> users { get; set; }
    public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
        users = new ObservableCollection<user>()
        {
            
            new Seller(){type=ptype.User,Name="user 1",Email=""},
            new Seller(){type=ptype.Seller,Name="seller 1",Email="",location="location 1",products_to_sell=""}
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;

    }

    private async void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        user p = (user)e.SelectedItem;
       await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page3(p));
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change person class in PersonDataTemplateSelector.

```
 public class PersonDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate userTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate sellerTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        return ((user)item).type==ptype.User ? userTemplate : sellerTemplate;
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to modify ContentPage binding property.

Comment: But my seller has some extra properties from what the user has. Like user has: name, email. And seller inherits from user and adds location and products_to_sell

Comment: @Nicoara I update my code, that you can take a look.